# Angular flex layout - too much repetition

Tags: css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I'm using the [responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API) of [angular flex layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). While usually everything behaves as expected I'm sometimes running into situations where directives are repeated throughout the code. Here is a stripped example:

```
<div>

  <div ngClass.lt-md="mobile-cell">
    <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true" class="mobile-label">Text1</span>
  </div>

  <div ngClass.lt-md="mobile-cell">
    <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true" class="mobile-label">Text2</span>
  </div>

  <div ngClass.lt-md="mobile-cell">
    <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true" class="mobile-label">Text3</span>
  </div>

  ....

</div>
```

Is there an elegant way (maybe involving pure css) to remove this duplication? For example to apply the `mobile-cell` class to all siblings  in case that the breakpoint is activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all direct child of `.parent` class is going to have the styles in `.mobile-cell` then just apply it to parent once and in css you can target all direct child `div`s of the parent `.mobile-cell`.

```
<div class="parent" ngClass.lt-md="mobile-cell">

  <div>
    <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true" class="mobile-label">Text1</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true" class="mobile-label">Text2</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true" class="mobile-label">Text3</span>
  </div>

  ....

</div>
```

```
.mobile-cell > div{
/* your style*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html

```
<div ngClass.lt-md="mobile-list">

    <div>
        <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true">Text1</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true">Text2</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span fxHide fxShow.lt-md="true">Text3</span>
    </div>

    ....

</div>
```

Your css:

```
.mobile-list > div {
    /* mobile-cell css */
}
.mobile-list > div > span {
    /* mobile-label css */
}
```